# How to use elastic search with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, asp.net-core

I have created a website which contains a large amount of data and I have used .Net Core with SQL Server to build the website, now I want to implement elastic search with SQL Server database, how can I proceed with this?

Do I need to maintain a separate database for elastic search or do I need to sync data from SQL Server to elastic search? What are the possible ways to implement it?

Comment: synch it from db to elastic , there are plugins availble

Answer (score 1):

Elastic is a database on it's own so it has it's own data files, it's own client lib and you will need to implement some logic to either

- Sync data that exists in sql server or
- Store data only in elastic and not in sql server.

A common choice (but not a must) is to have the "original" data in your sql server and sync it to elastic. Then you read only from elastic.

The default db client is https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net

Note that sql server provides full text search too.

Comment: How can we sync data from sql server to elastic

Comment: You'll have to write your own code that reads the relevant data from your SQL database and writes it to elastic. You can update elastic whenever you update a record in your SQL server (e.g. as part of your service implementation) or you can do it "batched", e.g. every n minutes you read all modified/added/deleted records from SQL server and write them to elastic.