# Is there any way to auto-update Elastic Search indexes on change of MS SQL server database records?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, elasticsearch

I'm looking into elastic search usage in .NET using SQL server database. Currently I'm using azure search service and there is a way to update search documents, but with elastic search, I haven't found any way yet. My project is written in .Net and C#.

Comment: You can use logstash with jdbc plugin to ingest from a database to elastic. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html

Comment: @AdamT I think, it works for MySQL, but not for MS SQL.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134223/how-to-use-elastic-search-with-sql-server-database#comment93171845_53135246

Comment: It should work for anything that provides JDBC connectivity.

Comment: @AdamT Ok, I will look into it. But my project is written in ASP.NET (C#) and JDBC connectivity is not useful.